# push firebase notification from ios device to anther using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, afnetworking

i push notification from clouding database (firebase server),but i want to
**how to push firebase notification(FCM) from ios device to anther using AFNetworking ????-**
Thanks

Comment: Read the doc https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/send-multiple

Answer (score 1):

Use firebase Cloud function from device to device message/notification. there is no need of **AFNetworking**. Cloud function are easy to use.
Refer this link : **https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/**